# SERP's saying meta data is blocked by the robots.txt file after issue resolved

Tags: robots.txt, google-index

Google crawled the robots.txt file when there was a mistake in it and the homepage was blocked.

In the Google SERP's it says that the meta data is blocked by the robots.txt.

The mistake in the file was resolved over 1 month ago but the message is still there in the SERP's.

I have tested this in the robots tester tool and Googlebot is allowed as well as using the Fetch tool when first resolved the issue.

As this is the homepage I would have thought this would have changed already.
Is there a way to find out if there is still an issue or I just have to wait it out?

Comment: Did you tried Google Robots Tester Tool? https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

Comment: Yes Sorry, Googlebot is allowed.

Comment: Are you able to determine when the homepage was last crawled by Google?

Comment: Use the Google Search Console Fetch as Google and Submit to Index if all looks okay. It may not update right away, however, it will when the regular googlebot comes by 1-2 days later. Otherwise, you will just have to wait.

Comment: Hey, the page was last crawled today. When we fixed the robots.txt issue I used the fetch tool in search Console.

Comment: You say that "the meta data is blocked by robots.txt".   That doesn't sound to me like the homepage itself is blocked anymore.   Maybe it is something else like images, JS, or CSS.